# I'm trying to launch a webdriver from a web app, try to launch it from a servlet.java

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I prepare a web interface that I could launch the webdriver , i used servlet.java Im using Jboss application server, when i try to run it i receive the exception

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Now if im doing right click --> run as java application .

Result: runing fine , no problem

BUT!!! i try to run it from a web application here is an example:

//servlet that receive a submit from a JSP page and i want the webdriver to start

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response)
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 

}
```

i get the above exception, i use the JBOSS application server and i try to build a JSP page that with a click of a button the automation will start.

Is it possible ? is it because i try to run it above the Jboss server ? because i cant find an answer....

Thanks for any help
Note: SQA refer me to here .

Answer (score 0):

Well, the

```
 Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

basically means, that you are about to run a Firefox browser (from the web) and start browsing in it. I suppose you don't have Firefox installed in your cloud :)

I have two possible solutions in my mind:

1)
try

```
 Webdriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

But I am not quite sure if it will help.

2) there is web based service to test pages, called simpletestIO - http://www.simpletest.io - this runs the tests from the internet, but it will be probably paid in the future. (I am not connected to the service BTW). But in general, it should do the job you are expecting to do